# How do I make KendoChart series fill color solid, instead of the default semi-transparent?

Tags: kendo-ui

In Kendo Area chart, if you enable/disable the "stack" option, you'll see that the series fill color is semi-transparent, by default. How do I make it a solid color?

PS I do not want to provide a custom series color, because my data is generated remotely, dynamically. I am happy to use the default colors, but since I'm stacking the series, I would like those colors to be solid so that they match the legend colors.

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found that the correct setting to control the level of transparency is "opacity", set within seriesDefaults scope:

```
    seriesDefaults: {
       type: "area",
       stack: true,
       opacity: 1
    },
```